# Postgresql referenced inserts inside triggers

Tags: postgresql, triggers, reference, transactions, insert

I have an issue with three tables, let call them table **source**, table **parent** and table **child**.

When a row is inserted on table **source**, an after insert trigger is triggered, inside the function attached two main tasks are done:
- First an insert on table **parent**, with the pk value taken from the **source**.
- Second an insert on table **child**, with a reference to the **parent** before inserted row.

What is happening is that a foreign_key_violation error is triggered when the second insert is tried to do.

This error disappear if I remove the reference constraint on table **child**.

But I wish to have this constraint.
I've tried with add to this constraint `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED`.
But the issue persist.

So all works as if the first insert remains invisible to the second one,
so the second insert can't reference the first one.

Comment: Please add a minimal version of your trigger/insert commands.

Comment: Well, when preparing the minimal version, I found the issue.

Comment: Well, when preparing the minimal version, I found the issue.
DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED on **child** foreign key works ok.
But on parent I had a column id serial primary key...., but I need to  reference a second column xx, not the id.
How REFERENCE by default reference the primary key and I've tried to set on the **child** the second column xx, the foreign_key_violation was triggering.

So eliminating the id serial primary key on parent, and setting xx as the primary key works ok.

Thanks a log @JimStewart. To prepare the snippet, help me a lot.

Comment: If you think you found an issue that might help others, you can answer your own question below, but also update the question with more details. Otherwise, if it's a simple typographical error or similar, and you've solved it, please delete your question.

Comment: I guess I will update the question, put the simplified sample, and after that the answer. I think this could help others.